How to specify a method reference sequence?
I've been trying to hack a bit around this very ugly looking piece of code in my codebase.
The original code looks like this:
Long variable = Optional.of(message)
    .map(Message::getPayload)
    .map(MessageContentClass::getVariable)
    .orElse(null);

Since it's repeated loads of times in the codebase, this was really annoying me. I've already managed to simplify this into a function like this:
public <T, K> T getVariableFromMessage(Message<K> message, Function<K, T> func) {
   return Optional.of(message)
      .map(Message::getPayload)
      .map(func)
      .orElse(null);
}

and it works nicely. However, there's also some message types, where the desired variable is nested a bit deeper into the message. Something along the lines of:
Long variable = Optional.of(message)
    .map(Message::getPayload)
    .map(MessageContentClass::getObject1)
    .map(Object1::getObject2)
    .map(Object2::getVariable)
    .orElse(null);

I don't even know if it's possible, but it would be neat to generify the first functions, so that I have (instead of a single Function<K,T>) an array of functions, where each one "points" to the type of the next, so that the first map would go from K -> T, the second one from T -> R and so on, until it would get to the final one. I've seen method declarations, where a generic type is introduced OUTSIDE the angle brackets, so perhaps something like that? It's also clear that what I'm looking for would work for any number of functions. If I wanted just two or three, I could simply put them individually as arguments.
Hope it's clear what I'm trying to do and thanks for reading the whole post :)

It is very unclear what you want. Can you show some code that you wish to write?

I can't show you code I wish to write, since I don't know how to write it. The result should be similar to the first generic method getVariableFromMessage, but instead of applying one mapping, it should apply more mappings sequentially. In the getVariableFromMessage method, there's one function passed as an argument, that takes K and transforms it into T. The desired method would have more functions, that transform K into R, then R into T, then T into something else and so on, spitting out the final desired result type.

No I don't mean you should show some valid code. If I understand correctly, you want to write getVariableFromMessage(message, Foo::bar, Bar::somethingElse, Baz::finalThing); Is that right? That is not possible in Java.

I was thinking about something along the lines of getVariableFromMessage(Message message, List<Function funcs), while checking that the n-th function maps to the type required by the (n+1)-th function.

@HeribertGreinix There is no way to do that type-safely. You can do it type unsafely, where each Function in the 'list of mapping operations' can be whatever, even if the types make no sense (i.e. function 1 maps a Message to a MessageContent, and function 2 maps an Integer to a Long which makes no sense at all, but, any solution available would allow you to write it, and it'll only asplode at runtime with a ClassCastException. Please update the question if you are still interested in that, otherwise, no answer will ever be forthcoming.

Well I mean, I am interested in that on a personal level, but given that you say it can blow up and it'd probably be quite tedious to implement, I'd say it's not worth implementing for a few methods. There should be a way to check the types in each iteration before a class-cast, so that it doesn't throw a ClassCastException, no?

@HeribertGreinix at runtime, maybe. But why is that relevant? What do you suggest you do instead of throwing? Returning Optional.empty()? Dear lord, this optional stuff really rots people's brains if that's the case. "If programmer wrote bug, do nothing, silently" is... do I need to spell it out?

Of course, but that'd be the programmer's fault for not passing in the correct mapping functions and it'd be better to handle it in a way that gets shown in the log in a controlled manner, rather than just a random class cast exception out of nowhere. Plus you won't get Sonar complaining about an unchecked class cast.

The original code you've shown looks better and cleaner than any viable alternative.

I mean, eh? It does, until it's repeated about fifteen times and then is followed by some logic for handling null values. I haven't posted the whole generified method for readability purposes, but it has options for logging errors and supplying a fallback value automatically.

You can't achieve this directly, at least in a type-safe way.
But your current method, accepting a function, supports chaining the mapping operations indirectly with Function.andThen().

Returns a composed function that first applies this function to its input, and then applies the after function to the result. If evaluation of either function throws an exception, it is relayed to the caller of the composed function.

Function<MessageContentClass> first = MessageContentClass::getObject1;
Function<MessageContentClass, Variable> finalFunc = first
  .andThen(Object1::getObject2)
  .andThen(Object2::getVariable);
Variable variable = getVariableFromMessage(message, finalFunc);


Thanks, although I decided against it in the end, this seems like the best solution. I'll also try writing a custom FunctionSequence type that does this automatically just for fun.

Chaining functions via andThen is not simpler than the initial chaining via map and it has not the null safety of the map steps. When the null handling is not needed for the intermediate steps, you can simply use Long variable = getVariableFromMessage(message, p -> p.getObject1().getObject2().getVariable()); Otherwise, just using the map steps on the Optional is the simplest solution.

You'd need a mapping function that maps all the way from the start to the end in one go, going through 'optional' at each intermediate step.
This is difficult.
Long variable = Optional.of(message)
    .map(Message::getPayload)
    .map(MessageContentClass::getObject1)
    .map(Object1::getObject2)
    .map(Object2::getVariable)
    .orElse(null);

Would have to turn into:
Function<Message, Long> func = m -> m.getPayload().getObject1().getObject2().getVariable();

So that you can then simply go Optional.of(message).map(func).orElse(null);
But the trick is that your function needs to dance around null pointer exceptions. One option is to actually catch them, returning an optional-none if it happens, but, this would also catch any NPEs thrown directly by the getters themselves; with your bog standard T getName() { return this.name; } style getter that cannot happen but it still distasteful that your code cannot tell the difference between a getter in the chain returning null and a getter itself throwing an NPE. If you want it:
public <I, O> Optional<O> longMap(Optional<I> in, Function<I, O> func) {
  return in.flatMap(i -> {
    try {
      return Optional.of(func.apply(i));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }
  });
}

Armed with that:
Long variable = longMap(Optional.of(message),
  m -> m.getPayload().getObject1().getObject2().getVariable())
  .orElse(null);

However, using Optional to dance around null is just a bad idea. If your codebase tosses nulls about with abandon then fix the codebase, or embrace it. This half-solution gets you the downsides of both, the upsides of neither, and hairy issues such as this very question as a bonus. (malus?)
If you must, make it far more clear that's what you've built:
static <O> Optional<O> nullSafe(Supplier<O> op) {
  try {
    return Optional.of(op.get());
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}

Which lets you do:
long v = nullSafe(() ->
  message
    .getPayload()
    .getObject1()
    .getObject2()
    .getLongVar()).orElse(10);

(Generally, if you are writing orElse(null) you've messed up).
Alternatively, advocate for the elvis operator or something similar; currently it is not in java, it is not on the roadmap, and it had been on the roadmap and rejected about a decade ago. What you 'want' is:
long v = message?.getPayload()?.getObject1()?.getObject2()?.getLongVar() ?: 10;

Where message?.getPayload() evaluates to null instead of resulting in an NPE if message is null, and x ?: 10 evaluates to x if x is not null, and 10 otherwise. This code would have the effect of giving you the value of getLongVar() if the entire chain is all not null, and 10 if any part of it was.
To be clear, this does not exist, and there are no easy ways to do it; the few ways that do exist involve catching NPE, as in the code shown in this answer.

Seeing the result, I agree this is a very bad idea. Without the compiler being explicitly aware of what type maps to what and the sequential structure, it makes no sense to implement, as the direct solution is much more readable and its not worth it just to replace like 6 occurrences.
That being said, it's shame that you can't, because the motivation for having done this without direct chaining is a much more granular control over the error handling.

You can simplify the methods generating an optional using Optional.ofNullable(something).  No need to generate NPE (from Optional.of()) just to catch it right after. This will still throw the exception, if the function generating the value itself throws a NPE.

@Chaosfire The code would change from using of to using ofNullable. I found this more readable. It's shorter, too. The 'performance downside' of that NPE is pointless to worry about here. if it's important this code isn't usable whether you use ofNullable or not, and if it's not important... it's not important. JVM hotspot engines tend to be able to eliminate stack trace production when it can detect they aren't used.
